# Extract questions and answers with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract some questions and answers from some files I'm reading but my regex isn't working for me:

```
from re import findall,DOTALL

text='''
category 1
1. question
a) answer
b) answer
2. question
a) answer
b) answer

category 2
3. question
a) answer
b) answer
'''
```

The format in the files is basically a numbered list with a variable number of indexed answers like `a)` `b)` or `a.` `b.` ... with the answers spanning several lines in places. I've tried this:

```
mo=findall(r"^\d\.(.+)(\w\)|\.(.+))+$",text,DOTALL)
print(mo)
```

I tried putting in capture groups to separate the questions from the answers, 
removing `"^"` gives the closest result but it's still junk and I don't understand why this happens:

```
[(' question\na) answer\nb) answer\n2. question\na) answer\nb) answer\ncategory 2\n3', '. question\na) answer\nb) answer\n', ' question\na) answer\nb) answer\n')]
```

I'm considering looking for a space between the answers in order to not pick up the "category" junk as a part of the answer or controlling my input more to support a format with no space as well.

I'm trying to get an output like(doesn't need to be a tuple, that's just what findall groups return):

```
[('question', 'answer', 'answer'), 
 ('question', 'answer', 'answer'), 
 ('question', 'answer', 'answer')]
```

Comment: what is you desired output for above example?

Comment: Avoid `from re import findall,DOTALL`. `re.` is such a tiny prefix that you might as well just `import re` and use `re.findall` which is more idiomatic and less surprising. For your questions, are they always groups of 3 (one question and two answers) or is it possible that there are more than two answers?

Comment: Edited in :)
All of my code is from * import * lol but you're right, I'm worried for ambigous functions.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get and the rules for it. Why not split with a double newline? `s.split("\n\n")`?

Comment: Damn, I didn't literally mean "import *", my actual file is a parsed pdf file which over-complicates the question, I might upload it or the extracted text but I've made sure to imply that the questions/answers may span several lines

Comment: Yes, you did specify that. Do the existing answers solve the problem? If not, consider updating your example to address a mistaken assumption that might have been made.

Comment: I wasn't very strict with what I needed because I was thinking that I'll implement whatever turns out to be the easiest/cleanest or all-encompasing, I put a space between the categories in the last second because it made format sense to me but all the answers rode on that fact. I mean it works, just saying how it's funny how the little things matter, no one size fits all solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing a monster regex for a multiline requirement, I'd use normal iteration and accumulation, more or less. You can split on `/\n(?=[a-z\d][).] )/gm` to extract the Q&A content only. Iterating over these chunks, if any are questions, start a new Q&A block, otherwise append to the existing one to accumulate the result.

```
import re

text = '''
category 1
1. q1
  q1 foobar
a) a1.a
b) a1.b
  some extra a1.b
2. q2
a) a2.a
b) a2.b
  some extra a2.b
c) a2.c
 blah a2.c

category 2
3. q3
a) a3.a
b) a3.b
extra a3.b
'''

qa = []
block = []

for chunk in re.split(r"\n(?=[a-z\d][).] )", text):
    if m:= re.match(r"\d+\. (.+)", chunk, re.S):
        qa.append(tuple(block))
        block = [m.group(1)]
    elif m := re.match(r"[a-z]+\) (.+?)(?=\n\n|$|[a-z]+\) )", chunk, re.S):
        block.append(m.group(1))

qa = qa[1:] + [tuple(block)]

for line in qa: 
    print(line)
```

Gives:

```
('q1\n  q1 foobar', 'a1.a', 'a1.b\n  some extra a1.b')
('q2', 'a2.a', 'a2.b\n  some extra a2.b', 'a2.c\n blah a2.c')
('q3', 'a3.a', 'a3.b\nextra a3.b')
```

Regex explanations:

- `/\n(?=[a-z\d][).] )/gs` does the splitting on newlines that lookahead to either of the two `a)` or `1.` patterns. This enables us to preserve the multiline chunks.
- `/\d+\. (.+)/gs` lets us identify a `1. question` chunk and capture the question body.
- `/[a-z]+\) (.+?)(?=\n\n|$|[a-z]+\) )/gs` matches the `a) answer` chunk. It's pretty much the same as the `1. question` chunk above, but it has to be a bit careful to trim the next content header, which wasn't handled by regex (1) above. This is what the `(?=\n\n|$|[a-z]+\) )` lookahead does: if the following is a double newline, end of string or `a)`, then don't include it in this answer.

Comment: It's probably faster than a monster regex and you put in effort, I saw the post before the edit too, hardly the slightest clue how the regex in here works but it picks up cyrlic unicode characters too, which is what I forgot to mention in the question, Works, does what I said I wanted ++

Comment: Glad it worked out. I'll add an explanation for the regex in a minute.

Comment: Eh, didn't mean to offend you with the revision mate, sorry, I thought I've only added to this solution not taken away what

Comment: No offense taken, but typically, you'd add your own answer and you can reference this answer.

Answer (score 1):

One simpler approach would be splitting each line and applying a `regex`, for example:

```py
import re


text='''
category 1
1. question
a) answer
b) answer
2. question
a) answer
b) answer

category 2
3. question
a) answer
b) answer
'''

question = re.compile(r'^\d+\.\s(.+)')
answer = re.compile(r'^[a-z]\)\s(.+)')

output = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    if question.match(line):
        output.append(question.findall(line))
    elif answer.match(line):
        output[-1].append(answer.findall(line)[0])

print(output)
>>> [['question', 'answer', 'answer'], ['question', 'answer', 'answer'], ['question', 'answer', 'answer']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiline questions and answers you may try this:

```
text='''
category 1
1. question 1
a) answer 1a
   second line of answer 1a
b) answer 1b
2. question 2
a) answer 2a
b) answer 2b
   second line of answer 2b

category 2
3. question 3
   second line of question 3
a) answer 3a
   second line of answer 3a
b) answer 3b
   second line of answer 3b
'''

quiz = []
for category in re.split("\n\n", text):
    qa = re.findall(r"^\d+\.\s+(.*?)(^[a-z][).](?:[^\n]|\n(?!\d))*)", category, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    for question, answers in qa:       
        quiz.append((question.strip(), *re.findall(r"^[a-z][).]\s+((?:[^\n]|\n(?![a-z]))*)", answers, re.MULTILINE)))

print (quiz)
```

The output is

```
[('question 1', 'answer 1a\n   second line of answer 1a', 'answer 1b'), ('question 2', 'answer 2a', 'answer 2b\n   second line of answer 2b'), ('question 3\n   second line of question 3', 'answer 3a\n   second line of answer 3a', 'answer 3b\n   second line of answer 3b\n')]
```

Since there is no specification in the question how to handle lines ending/spaces in the multiline questions and answers it's hard to understand if this output satisfies the requirements or not.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it doesn't produce OP's output. Also, downvoters have no obligation to explain themselves. Lots of good meta topics: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not) [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: Well, for single lines it does, and not enough specifications for multilines.